# Getting a list of all object variables regardless of modifier PHP

Tags: php, oop

I want to get an array of all of the variables in a class, including the private variables, without having to instantiate the object. I am aware of php's get_class_vars() but it only shows the variables that are in scope. I am calling this from outside the class, so all the private variables are hidden.

My intention is to create a page with all of the variables for each object listed, and I don't want to instantiate each object because they all require different identifiers to instantiate, and I would like to avoid having to pass a bunch of ids to the page if possible.

Please note, the values of the variables are unimportant, I only want the variable names.

Comment: By the way, you should consider [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) before making it all on your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php), Luke.

With `ReflectionClass::getProperties`, you can get all fields of a class.

e.g.

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('YourClass');

foreach( $reflection -> getProperties() as $field )
{

    echo $field ."\n";

}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Is there a way to get the name without doing a bunch of string manipulation?

Comment: Never mind, I wasn't treating the $field value as an object. Using $field->name worked perfectly.